# change State after onPressIn and onPressOut TextInput react-native

Tags: react-native, function, use-state, textinput

i want to change useState boolean value after focusing on textinput and also after touching out of it. but it doesn't work. what is my mistake?

```
const {chatmode,setChatmode} = useState(false);

    return(
            <View style={[styles.chat,{zIndex:chatmode? 1 :-1}]}>
                <TextInput style={styles.chatinput} onPressOut={()=> setChatmode(false)} onPressIn={setChatmode(true)}/>
            </View>
    )
```

result error is :

```
TypeError: setChatmode is not a function. (In 'setChatmode(true)', 'setChatmode' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `[]` brackets not curly brackets as follows

```js
const [chatmode, setChatmode] = useState(false)
```

**Edit:** To answer your question concerning `onPressOut`. You could wrap your `TextInput` into `Pressable`.

```js
<View>
       <Pressable onPressIn={() => console.log("in")} onPressOut={() => console.log("out")}>
         <TextInput></TextInput>
       </Pressable>
</View>
```

Comment: ohh i can't believe i made that mistake :)). i was getting crazy. but OnPressOut is not what i want! what is the right way to do a function when i touch out of text input ?